# How to customize color corresponding to specific values in ListSliceContourPlot3D

Tags: plotting

I am trying to make a 3D contour plot I calculated in c++. I read in the results as tables and used the function ListSliceContourPlot3D.

This is what I got so far

[image]

I want to highlight the zero regions (region with value < 0.0001) using a white color,

i.e. purple -> white

Here is my code

```
data3d = Import["simulation220.txt", 
   "table"];
dim = Dimensions[data3d];
l = dim[[1]]/dim[[2]]; m = dim[[2]]; n = dim[[2]];
cuboid = Table[1, {x, l}, {y, m}, {z, n}];
For[i = 1, i < l + 1, i++, a = n*(i - 1) + 1; b = n*i; 
  cuboid[[i]] = data3d[[a ;; b]]];
ListSliceContourPlot3D[cuboid, {"ZStackedPlanes", {1, 87, 174}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}], 
 Contours -> {0.0001, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}, 
 ContourStyle -> Black, PlotRange -> {All, All, All, {-.5, 1}}, 
 Axes -> False, ClippingStyle -> White, AspectRatio -> 1.5, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

and here is my data [simulation220](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1U_aB0DNUvNvQE7AxYCAjd34T7VFKxKyo/view?usp=sharing)

All the numbers in my data are positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
threshold = .0001;
contours = {threshold, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9};
```

### 1. [`ContourShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourShading.html)

```
contourshading = Prepend[ConstantArray[Automatic, Length[contours]], White];

ListSliceContourPlot3D[cuboid, {"ZStackedPlanes", {1, 87, 174}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}],
 ContourShading -> contourshading, 
 Contours -> contours, ContourStyle -> Black, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, All, {-.5, 1}}, Axes -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> 1.5, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

### 2. Custom color function:

```
cf = If[# <= threshold, White, ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}][#]] &;

ListSliceContourPlot3D[cuboid, {"ZStackedPlanes", {1, 87, 174}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 ColorFunction -> cf,
 Contours -> contours, ContourStyle -> Black, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All, All, {-.5, 1}}, Axes -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> 1.5, ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a `Blend` of "Rainbow" colors with purple threshold set to 0.0001.

```
colorFunction = Blend[{
{0.0001, RGBColor[1., 0.99997, 0.999985]}, {0.0625, 
 RGBColor[0.31106, 0.11758, 0.664469]},
{0.125, RGBColor[0.250728, 0.225386, 0.769152]}, {0.1875, 
 RGBColor[0.24408, 0.361242, 0.816084]},
{0.25, RGBColor[0.266122, 0.486664, 0.802529]}, {0.3125, 
 RGBColor[0.305919, 0.585575, 0.739666]},
{0.375, RGBColor[0.36048, 0.655759, 0.645692]}, {0.4375, 
 RGBColor[0.429842, 0.701849, 0.540321]},
{0.5, RGBColor[0.513417, 0.72992, 0.440682]}, {0.5625, 
 RGBColor[0.607651, 0.743718, 0.358588]},
{0.625, RGBColor[0.705038, 0.742591, 0.299167]}, {0.6875, 
 RGBColor[0.794549, 0.721158, 0.260829]},
{0.75, RGBColor[0.863512, 0.670771, 0.236564]}, {0.8125, 
 RGBColor[0.901014, 0.582826, 0.216542]},
{0.875, RGBColor[0.902853, 0.453964, 0.192014]}, {0.9375, 
 RGBColor[0.878107, 0.293208, 0.160481]},
{1., RGBColor[0.857359, 0.131106, 0.132128]}}, #1] &
```

[image]